# Add support for Drupal.org profiles in careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Could you add support for Drupal.org profiles? I have plenty of code there, and I would like to link some as the same way I can link my github projects.

Comment: We've got something in the works, hopefully deployed this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we've added an "other..." option under Open Source on your profile. If your Drupal project is not open source, your will also find an "Other Projects" area.